Scrape player data rotowire.com in python
I am trying to get/scrape the Batting stats table from this page:
https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/player/cj-abrams-16042
Looking at the page further I think all the tables probably the same to get so if theres some soup.find_all() or something so could get other tables would be appreciated.
If unable to get other tables would appreciate if could at least get the stat review since seems to be similar to current year stats and if I press view source on the page I can actually see the values but I dont get from the driver.page_source in my code.
I tried requests.get() but was not seeing any table or anything when was parsing through the html and also since the page was loading stats so thought maybe would be better with selenium, but with selenium still no sign of the stats/table in the data I tried adding implicitywait(100) too see if would give page more time to load tables but didnt seem to change anything also in the view source of the page it says loading a bunch of places also tried WebDriverWait and that also did not help.
Relevant code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') 
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) 
url = "https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/player/cj-abrams-16042"
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(soup)


I'm not experienced with Rotowire, but in general before I try selenium, I'd make sure there wasn't some easy API that's ready to use. It doesn't look like the stats you want are rotowire-specific, they're readily available on baseballreference. In which case, why not use something like pybaseball to do it for you?

From rotowire would be preferred since looking at stats based for each player in a teams lineup is the overall idea and from the rotowire page with lineups each players name is a link to their respective page and when I was looking at some other places for stats names can be hard to match for example some places use accents on players names and some dont so may have trouble matching names correctly also some stat APIs ive seen use like a playerid as a parameter which im not sure how would get ahead of time, so I thought would be easier if get stats from the same place get lineup from

This website has an API, which you can see on the XHR requests made by the browser. An example is below
https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/ajax/player-page-data.php?id=16042&stats=batting

looks like you just have to provide the id of the player which is already defined on the URL after the name


Thanks. Just to confirm I dont need an API key or anything to do this tho right?

seems like you don't need any API key. I was able to call the same endpoint using postman just giving the id and stats as parameters
